# What is Caffenol?

Tags: film, developing

I've been hearing about [Caffenol](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=Caffenol) and understand it's film developer (for example in [these](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88248/what-do-properly-developed-negatives-look-like) [three](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87846/why-do-all-my-film-color-negatives-come-out-transparent) [questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/what-are-the-results-of-developing-slide-film-e-6-process-with-c41-chemicals) ).

**What is it exactly?** How do I get it? How is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caffenol is a home-made developer that seems to be gaining popularity among enthuisiasts, especially due to [non-toxic compounds and environmentally friendly footprint](http://www.caffenol-cookbook.com/).

According to [Caffenol @Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffenol):

> There are many formulas for caffenol. All are based on preparations which contain caffeic acid (i.e. coffee or tea) and a pH modifier, most often sodium carbonate.

And indeed, searching for "[Caffenol recipes](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=Caffenol+recipe)" yields many results. For example, [@ToastHouse](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/61494/toasthouse) mentions the following recipe in a couple of the linked questions:

> I use 10 teaspoons of Folgers Instant Coffee Crystals, 7 teaspoons of Arm & Hammer Washing Soda, and 1 teaspoon of Ascorbic Acid Vitamin C for the developer. I use a bit of Heinz Distilled White Vinegar mixed with tap water for a stop bath, and 8 oz tap water, 2 oz of Ilford Rapid Fixer for the fixer.

Note that development times are [usually longer](http://www.digitaltruth.com/devchart.php?Film=&Developer=Caffenol&mdc=Search) that *off the shelf* developers.

Comment: With a name like that, I would have guessed it was Irish coffee.  :-D